# Stuck on partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm stuck on a very simple task.

> $$
> \left\{
> \begin{array}{}
> u = x^2-y^2\\
> v=2xy
> \end{array}
> \right.
> $$
>   1) (**Solved**) Calculate $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(1,1)$
>
> $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 2x, \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(1,1) = 2$$
>
> 2) (**Stuck**) Calculate $\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}(0,2)$

I looked at a rule: $\frac{d(u)}{d(x)} = \frac{1}{\frac{d(x)}{d(u)}}$ but that I believe that theorem was just to give the relations between the functional determinants which is not the case here.

I have really tried to check my book so what have I not understood?

By the way the correct answer is $\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}(0,2) = \frac{1}{4}$

Comment: Are you sure it's not supposed to say
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(2,0) = \frac{1}{4}
$$

Comment: if you take $\frac{\partial}{\partial u}$ on both sides of the first equation, you get
$$
1 = 2x \frac{\partial x}{ \partial u} - 2y \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}
$$

Comment: Well done not falling into the trap in the second problem: a common error made by beginners in this subject is to compute the reciprocal of $\partial u/\partial x$. Have you learned about the Jacobian of a multivariable function yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem statement should maybe have specified that $\partial_x u$ must be evaluated at $(x,y) = (1, 1)$ in the first case, and that $\partial_u x$ must be evaluated at $(x,y) = (2, 0)$ in the second case -- or alternatively at something like $(u,v) = (4,0)$.
Whatever is asked here, we have
$$
u \pm \text i v = x^2 \pm 2\text i xy - y^2 = (x\pm \text i y)^2
$$
$$
\text{and}\qquad
x\pm \text i y = (u \pm \text i v)^{1/2} .
$$
Thus
$
\frac{\partial}{\partial u} (x\pm \text i y) = \tfrac12 (u \pm \text i v)^{-1/2}
$. The linear average of the $+$ and $-$ equations gives
\begin{aligned}
\tfrac{\partial}{\partial u} x &= \tfrac14 \big[ (u + \text i v)^{-1/2} + (u - \text i v)^{-1/2} \big] \\
&= \tfrac14 \big[ (x + \text i y)^{-1} + (x - \text i y)^{-1} \big]\\ &= \tfrac12\tfrac{x}{x^2+y^2} \, .
\end{aligned}
If you manage to find the missing information in the problem statement, then you can conclude.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear, but perhaps the second question should be understood as $\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}$ at $(u,v)=(0,2)$. For this we need to treat $x$ as a function of $u$ and $v$. We get:

$$x^2=u+y^2=u+\frac{v^2}{4x^2}$$
$$x^4-ux^2-\frac{v^2}{4}=0$$
$$4x^3\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}-x^2-2ux\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}=\frac{x^2}{4x^3-2ux}$$

At $(u,v)=(0,2)$, we have $x^2=y^2$ and $xy=1$, so $x=\pm 1$. Therefore
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}(0,2)=\pm\frac14$$

which is almost what you want. Did the question say anything about whether $x$ had to be positive?